# Selected item in ListFragment doesn't get highlighted

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to highlight a previous selected item in my ListFragment but it's not working for me. The highlighting is the only issue since I'm able to see what I selected in the console but the coloring is just not working for whatever reason.

This is the code I use to highlight it

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ListView view = getListView();
    TextView previousSelected = null;
    int selectedPosition = 0;
    if(view != null) {
        int adapterSize = view.getAdapter().getCount();
        if (selectedView != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < adapterSize; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "view getchildat " + view.getAdapter().getView(i, null, view) + " selected " + selectedView);
                if (((TextView) view.getAdapter().getView(i, null, view)).getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(((TextView) selectedView).getText().toString())){
                    previousSelected = (TextView) view.getAdapter().getView(i, null, view);
                    Log.d(TAG, "selected is " + previousSelected.getText().toString());
                    view.setSelection(i);
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    view.setFocusable(true);
                    selectedPosition = i;
                }
            }
        } else if (tagScan.getLastFeedback()[0] != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "count fragment is " + count);
            for(int i = 0; i < adapterSize; i++){
                Log.d(TAG, "view getchildat " + ((TextView)view.getAdapter().getView(i, null, view)).getText().toString() + " selected " + tagScan.getLastFeedback()[count]);
                if (((TextView) view.getAdapter().getView(i, null, view)).getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(tagScan.getLastFeedback()[count])){
                    previousSelected = (TextView) view.getAdapter().getView(i, null, view);
                    Log.d(TAG, "selected is " + previousSelected.getText().toString());
                    view.setSelection(i);
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    view.setFocusable(true);
                }
            }
        }
        if(previousSelected != null){
            Log.d(TAG,"set color of the previous selection " + previousSelected.getText().toString());
            previousSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            previousSelected.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            selectedView = previousSelected;

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use selectors, but no luck there either:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected"/>
    <item
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected"/>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected"/>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected"/>
    <!--<item-->
        <!--android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected" />-->
</selector>
```

The highlighting works fine in an `onClickListener` for me so I'm not sure why it's not working in the `onStart`.

Comment: Can you try to move it to `onViewCreated` or `onResume` instead of `onStart`? That might be the issue here.

Comment: Tried both still no luck sadly

Comment: How does the xml of item looks like?

Comment: I don't have an xml for item, do you mean the `list_selector_selected`?

Comment: I see, maybe you should consider using `RecyclerView` to have more flexibility here and have your custom item view, where you set your selector.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work, it tells me I can't use `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'` because I need to install the Android Support Repository which I already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by override the `getView` of the adapter like so

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.feedback_list, feedback.getOptions()){
                            @Override
                            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                                Log.d(TAG,"view is " + view + " selected is " + listFragment.selectedView);
                                if(listFragment.selectedPosition != null) {
                                    if (listFragment.selectedPosition[0] == position) {
                                        view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
                                    }
                                }
                                return view;
                            }
                        };
```